# How to do a bulk insert without overwriting existing data - Pymongo?

Tags: python, pymongo, bulkinsert

I am trying to bulk insert data to MondoDB without overwriting existing data. I want to insert new data to the database if no match with unique id (sourceID). Looking at the documentation for Pymongo I have written some code but cannot make it work. Any ideas to what I am doing wrong?

```
db.bulk_write(UpdateMany({"sourceID"}, test, upsert=True))
```

db is the name of my database, SourceID is the unique ID of the documents that I don't want to overwrite in the existing data, test is the array that I am tying to insert.

Answer (score 0):

Either I don't understand your requirement or you misunderstands the `UpdateMany` operation. As per [documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/operations.html#pymongo.operations.UpdateMany), this operation serves for modifying the existing data (those matching the query) and only if no documents match the query, and `upsert=True`, insert new documents. Are you sure you don't want to use [`insert_many`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many) method?

Also, in your example, the first parameter which should be a filter for update, is not a valid query which has to be in a form `{"key": "value"}`.